# how cover dmlexeption on test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

i have to write test for delete record i tries this code
Apex:

```
public class modalaction{
public string cid{get;set;}
    public void deletecon(){
        Contact cons = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where id=:cid]; 
        system.debug('con:'+cons );
        delete cons; 
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
modalaction modal = new modalaction();
 modal.first='p';
       modal.last='test';
        modal.em = 'test@gmail.com';
    contact c = new contact();
    c.firstname = 'p';
    c.lastname = 'test';
    c.email = 'test@gmail.com';
    insert c;
 modal.cid = c.id;
    Contact cons = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where id=:c.id]; 
    system.debug(+cons);
    delete cons;
    modal.deletecon();
```

Error:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) about testing in Salesforce.

The error you get means that your `deletecon` method can't find any record with the id linked to its `cid` variable.

And this is totally normal, because in your test, before calling the deletecon method, you delete the contact record. You just have to create a contact record, assign its id to the cid variable, then call the `deletecon` method. Finally, check with assert if the delete worked:

```
contact c = new contact();
c.firstname = 'p';
c.lastname = 'test';
c.email = 'test@gmail.com';
insert c;

modal.cid = c.id;
modal.deletecon();

System.assertEquals(0, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c.Id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code.

```
modalaction modal = new modalaction();
 modal.first='p';
       modal.last='test';
        modal.em = 'test@gmail.com';
    contact c = new contact();
    c.firstname = 'p';
    c.lastname = 'test';
    c.email = 'test@gmail.com';
    insert c;
 modal.cid = c.id;
    Contact cons = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where id=:c.id]; 
    system.debug(+cons);
    delete cons; //Cons u manually deleted
    modal.deletecon();//Now trying to delete via method
```

As you are deleting contact in test class via **delete cons**, and then calling your class method to delete it again, you are getting the list has no rows for assignment . Which is obvious.

Quickfix, remove the **delete cons;** line in your test class